# Android Kotlin Can we put combination of text and image icon to the checkbox?

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, radio-button

Made toppings checkboxes with only text, wonder can I add a small image to it.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkWhippedCream"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingEnd="24dp"
        android:text="@string/whipped_cream"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can by using `android:drawableEnd` (could be any side: Bottom, Top, Start, End)

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkWhippedCream"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:text="@string/whipped_cream"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawabale/your_icon"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: How to define a size for it?

Comment: You can't define it, you should use the icon with desired size